# "dynamic set" in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a table where one column will have a few values many times (maybe 20 different values). Now I would like to use something like the set to improve performance and memory consumption. The problem is that I don't know which values I'm going to have so I can't  use the normal set as I have to define the values in the create statement.

What could I do to achieve this?

More specific i will have a table where i list schoolbooks, and each of these books is associated to a subject. Now the same subject will appear in multiple datarows. But as I don't know which subjects will exist I can't use the set.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post an example of what you mean, it's unclear to me.

Comment: edited the question.

Comment: Don't use SET or ENUM types - they're non standard and non portable. What you need is a lookup table - a small table with all your possible values and make your value in your other table a foreign key pointing at that lookup table. Unless you want something like record1 myBooks = 'book1, book2', record2 myBooks = 'book1, book3, book4' or similar. This is a disaster and a breach of Codd's rules. If that is your thinking, you should redesign.

Comment: Check out this http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/